# Does sudo apt upgrade update my microcode?

Tags: linux, cpu, updates

So the question above in more generally: does the linux updates (on ubuntu, 
 redhat, debian, etc...) update my microcode as well? or I have to update my CPU's microcode manually?

Comment: should be on https://superuser.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Debian has `intel-microcode` & `amd64-microcode` packages. When it is updated, some microcode gets updated. But your question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are packages with Intel and AMD CPU microcode. You need to have them installed to have this done.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=microcode&searchon=names&suite=artful&section=all